# Create C++ unmanaged DLL using VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, unmanaged

I have created a dll project in VS2010 (Win32 console application>dll). I put some header files in the project when I compile I get this error:

```
error LINK2001: unresolved external symbol _dllmaincrtstartup@12
```

What is this? How do I fix it?
Also the header files define a number of abstract classes.

Comment: If it's a console app, why do you need a dll?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: The wizard in VS is a bit misleading - first you have to choose "Win32 Console Application" and then in a second step choose "DLL".

Comment: The project wizard has several entry points and that is confusing. However you get to the Win32 Application Wizard, on the last page, under "Application Settings" dialog, you want to select "Console Application" not "DLL".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Q: It's the .dll that's failing to build (and not an .exe that uses the .dll), correct?

Q: Does anything in your .dll source have a DllMain()?

If not, would you consider adding one?

Q: Are you sure the project settings are configured for "DLL"?  For "/MT" (multi-threaded, static link)?

Q: Failing all else, have you considering creating a NEW project, creating a "hello world" .dll, and verifying that it builds?

Comment: No. Should it? What is it for?

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, the dll is failing. I haven't yet created a project to use it. DLLMain doesn't exist. Adding `void DLLMain() {}` does not help. All I know is that configuration type is set to Dynamic Link Library (.dll).

Comment: I created another project and added a header file with a single Hello function that prints "Hello World!". When I compile I get the same error as before

Comment: Adding DllMain to a .cpp file solved it. Now it compiles. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear from the answer why adding `DllMain` resolves different missing symbol, `_dllmaincrtstartup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **/NOENTRY** option which is required for creating a **resource-only DLL**. Use this option to prevent LINK from linking a reference to _main into the DLL.

**Project Property Pages -> Linker -> Advanced: No Entry Point** set to **Yes (/NOENTRY)**

"**DLL** containing objects compiled with /clr is not linked with **/NOENTRY**; image may not run correctly"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814472

Comment: I don't think this question is about resource-only DLLs.

Comment: But last comment is "Adding DllMain to a .cpp file solved it. Now it compiles. Thanks. –  atoMerz Dec 10 '11 at 22:33" I gues it is resource-only DLL.

Comment: "Also the header files define a number of abstract classes" -> does not sound like resource only. It sounds like they somehow did not get the wizard to work correctly (or chose the wrong options).